# Validate an Access Text Box to an ODBC SQL Column using VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I've been asked to validate a text box against a Database column to confirm that it is correct (confirmation only) although it seems I have having trouble connecting to the data source (an ODBC connected linked table) 
if anyone could highlight where I am going wrong. my VBA is almost non existent.

```vb
Private Sub Command65_Click()

    Dim sCnxnStr As String
    Dim db As database
    sCnxnStr = "ODBC;DSN=Matrix"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim queryString As String '"SELECT "SERIAL" FROM ["TABLE]" WHERE "SERIAL" = "'Serial Number' "'.
    If "SERIAL" = "'Serial Number'" Then
    MsgBox "Serial Number is Correct'.", 16, msgboxtitle
    Else
    MsgBox "Serial Number is Not Correct'.", 16, msgboxtitle
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This might simplify it:

```
Dim buf
Dim SerialNumber As String
SerialNumber = "123"

buf = DLookup("Serial", "Table", "Serial = '" & SerialNumber & "'")
If Not IsNull(buf) Then
    MsgBox "Serial Number is Correct.", 1, msgboxtitle
Else
    MsgBox "Serial Number is Not Correct.", 1, msgboxtitle
End If
```

Comment: ok thanks, although the issue is now, Runtime error 3078, Cannot find the input table or query 'Table'. Which I think was the issue with the original code.

Comment: That error suggests your table is not named `Table`.  Double-check your table name and use the correct name in the `DLookup`.